# Trying to cross map 2 dictionaries together, Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I am trying to do a bit of data transformation using Python dicts.

`dict1 = {'email1':'id1', 'email2': 'id2', ..}`

`dict2 = {'abbreviation': ['email1', 'email2', 'email3', ..], 'abbreviation2': ['email2', 'email3', 'email4', ...], ...}`

What I want to do is a dict which will have something like this as output:

`result = {'abbreviation': [id1, id2, ...]}`

I have tried

```py
needed_ids = dict()
temp_list = list()

for email, id in dict1.items():
    for abbrev, list_of_emails in dict_results.items():
        if email in list_of_emails:
            # Get the abbreviation of the language
            temp_lst.append(id)
            needed_ids[abbrev] = temp_lst
```

This gave me only 1 value in the temp list and not all the ids values.
Any hints please?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is almost correct you just need to change one part so that it looks like this

```
needed_ids = dict()

for email, id in dict1.items():
    for abbrev, list_of_emails in dict2.items():
        if email in list_of_emails:
            # Get the abbreviation of the language
            current_ids = needed_ids.get(abbrev,[])
            current_ids.append(id)
            needed_ids.update({abbrev:current_ids})
```

In this version you are getting the ids of the current abbrev or if there are none it returns an empty list. you then append to that list and place it back into the dictionary using the update function

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate over the emails list in `dict2` and get the matching id from `dict1`

```
dict1 = {'email1':'id1', 'email2': 'id2'}
dict2 = {'abbreviation': ['email1', 'email2', 'email3'], 'abbreviation2': ['email2', 'email3', 'email4']}

needed_ids = dict()

for abbrev, list_of_emails in dict2.items():
    for email in list_of_emails:
        if email in dict1:
            needed_ids[abbrev] = needed_ids.get(abbrev, []) + [dict1[email]]
```

You can also convert it to dict comprehensions if you like

```
needed_ids = {abbrev: [dict1[email] for email in list_of_emails if email in dict1]
              for abbrev, list_of_emails in dict2.items()}
```

Output:

```
{'abbreviation': ['id1', 'id2'], 'abbreviation2': ['id2']}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is by using a default dictionary then fill it with a separate loop as follows :

```
dict1 = {'email1': 'id1', 'email2':'id2', 'email3':'id3', 'email4':'id4', 'email5':'id5'}
dict2 = {'abbreviation': ['email1', 'email2', 'email3'], 'abbreviation2': ['email2', 'email3', 'email4', 'email5']}

# first store the keys and values into lists
idx_list, abrev_list = [], []  
for abrev in dict2.keys():
    for email, idx in dict1.items():
        if email in dict2[abrev]:
            abrev_list.append(abrev)
            idx_list.append(idx)

# create a default dictionary
from collections import defaultdict
result = defaultdict(list)

# fill dictionary with a different loop
for k, v in zip(abrev_list, idx_list):
    result[k].append(v)

dict(result)

>>> {'abbreviation': ['id1', 'id2', 'id3'],
     'abbreviation2': ['id2', 'id3', 'id4', 'id5']}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).